# Paypal Billing Agreement Cancellation

Tags: paypal

To cancel a Billing Agreement created by a customer, Paypal gives an API which `METHOD=BillAgreementUpdate` to cancel a billing agreement. But when a user cancels the agreement by logging into his account, how do we find this out?

Does paypal send a notification when the agreement is cancelled or is there any API call we could use to check whether the agreement exists or not? I couldn't find any information about any such notifications from searching on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal does not give any IPN if user cancels billing agreement. It can only be identified by error thrown when corresponding API call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It'll give you what you want.